# Chuzhakin's System Hazardous Elements and Rules

Tags: tactics, blunder

A short time ago, I ran across some short texts and a short video about Chuzhakin's system to spot tactics and avoid blunders.

What little I've seen seems really to help me. And so I'm looking for the complete list of hazardous elements and rules or the complete text. Everywhere is mentioned a pdf.

Also, there are a lot of links to Chuzhakin's pdf (at neoneuro.com...) in the net, but all of them lead to 404 Page not found...  Some hours of searching the net for the text lead to no result.

Could somebody please post the pdf or the maybe list of hazardous elements and the counting rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled the name of the file, chuzhakinssystem.pdf, and found a copy here: https://docplayer.net/22332201-Chuzhakin-s-system-version-2-14.html

Better yet, it can be found using the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180219185540/https://neoneuro.com/downloads/chuzhakinssystem.pdf . I think this link is more likely to be stable.